# Implementation for Class Association Rule mining from transaction database?

Tags: data-mining, association-rules

It seems to me that all the implementation for **Class Association Rules mining** is used for relational database. If that's not true, could you please suggest me a tool that can take the **transaction database** for input? If I were to convert my data set (50k transactions, 400k items) to relational form, it would become very large (50GB).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for such tools (like I am now), here are some links. These are not for databases but general python tools for association rule mining with transaction data.

- For class association rule mining there is [CARMine](https://github.com/FlightDataServices/carmine/tree/master/carmine).
- While not strictly for class association rule, there is [Apriori](https://github.com/asaini/Apriori), which is a more popular library specifically for rule association mining.
- The [MLXtend](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/) machine learning support library offers apriori frequent itemset creation and association rule generation modules.

Comment: could you provide some references for your links, just in case they die in the future? thanks

Comment: @Antoine: I think I have done it, let me know if you think I can enhance it further. Thx!